# XSL-FO tags not supported in Java

Tags: apache, tags, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to edit an XSL-FO document to be processed in Java via Apache FOP.   Are there any tags that might not be supported or that have become depreciated?

I didn't write the original XSL-FO.  It was originally a WordML document that I converted via Word2FO, and I've gotten rid of junk characters and made sure all the tags are closed properly, so the only thing I can think of is that some of these tags might not be supported.  Particularly:

- Tags with Microsoft-related properites, including fonts like Arial-Word-Unicode, references to Microsoft-Office Smarttags, and other word-related properties
- SVG tags
- External graphics tags with huge streams of nonsense text to represent an image.

I've been looking online for a list of these unsupported tags, but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I am looking for on this page.

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html

Very useful for looking up what is/isn't supported.

I should really stop finding these solutions after asking these questions.

This question is answered, and the above link will probably help anyone who needs it answered too. Sorry to bother the rest of you.